# VS Code adds spaces between content when pasting

Tags: visual-studio-code, copy, text-editor, paste

When I copy this, for example:

```html
<AdmobComponent/>
```

It pastes as:

```html
< AdmobComponent / >
```

Does anyone have any suggestions? I don't even know where to start to fix this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From within the IDE:

Go to `File` | `Preferences` | `Settings` and then click `Text Editor` | `Formatting`.
The top option should be `FormatOnPaste`, make sure this is unchecked.

If you are using the [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) extension, then this is a [known issue](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/245).

Answer (score 5):

For anyone having a similar problem in Visual Studio 2019 it can be fixed as follows:

Go to Tools | Options | Text Editor | {language}

Now depending on the Language the options that need to be changed could be in a few different places or missing. But for C# and JavaScript go to Code Style | Formatting

Once there there are a few options. If "Automatically format on paste" is unticked it will completely remove any reformatting on paste.

Or for a more limited impact go into the "Spacing" section and change "Set spacing for operators" to "Ignore spaces around binary operators". By doing this some automatic reformatting is lost but I think it's worth it not to have all those spaces inserted into stuff like Kebab case variables.

Comment: For those using R Tools for Visual Studio, it's in Tools > Options > Text Editor > R > Advanced > Format on paste (Off)